U-Boot tftp is much faster then linux tftp
I am using bitbake to generate my u-boot and linux images. I have two boards, one of which is running a simple TFTP server written in c++ code.
U-Boot can tftp boot ~50MB in around 7 seconds. When it boots in the the linux image it just TFTP booted from it takes about 2.5 minutes.
I was using the builtin busybox tftp, so I thought that might be the issue. So I added tftp-hpa to my linux image and re-tried with that tftp <ipaddr> -m binary -c get <file> and got basically the same result.
The tftp server always writes 512 byte chunks and reports and re-tries, which there are none.
So I am at a bit of a loss to explain this difference. Its all the exact hardware, the only difference is one is running from u-boot and the other is running from Linux.
What might be the difference? - any way I can test/resolve this?
Clarifications

U-boot takes 7 seconds to tftp-get/transfer the FIT image from the server
Linux (once booted) takes 2.5 minutes to tftp-get/transfer the same image
By adding tftp-hpa to my bitbake recepie, it has replaced the busybox implementation
My question is how to make the linux tftp transfer the same speed as the u-boot transfer.
The simple c++ tftp server is on a separate board, running on linux, its always running and is left unchanged for all these tests

Update
Using rsync to copy the files when in linux is very fast also... so that is a workaround - but still does not answer why tftp in linux is so slow.

I can't tell if you're asking about the speed of transferring 50MB from the tftp server to the client, or asking about the speed booting into Linux from the 50MB file that was transferred.  Also, is "U-boot" the "simple TFTP server written in c++ code"?  Your description doesn't make that clear.

AND "So I added tftp-hpa to my linux image", but did you either remove the original tftp and mv tftp-hpa tftp OR did you really mean you are now using tftp-hpa instead of tftp for your testing?

@SottoVoce apologies, I have added some clarifications

@shellter also apologies, I have added some clarifications

It's quite likely you know more than I do about this, so when you say "I added tftp-hpa to my linux image and re-tried with that tftp <ipaddr> -m binary -c get <file>" , why did you use tftp-hpa <ipaddr> -m binary -c get <file>, OR did you prove to yourself that the old tftp has been overwritten with the tftp-hpa version, perferably using something like ls -l /usr/bin/tftp* ? Good luck.

@shellter yes bitbake has configured /usr/bin/tftp to be a symlink to tftp-hpa
